# Login or unlock screen on a Mac using an NFC tag?

Tags: usb, login, screen-lock, login-screen, authentication

Does OSX have support for unlocking the screen (or logging in) using a NFC or RFID tag?

The [ACS ACR122T USB NFC dongle](http://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/109/acr122t-usb-tokens-nfc-reader/) (a [PC/SC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC/SC) device) seems to have working OSX drivers, but no software suite for login is available.  Rumors has it that [Dangerous Things](http://dangerousthings.com/) are working on that.

A workaround is to use a RFID/NFC reader that acts as an [HID/input device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class), such as the [RfidLoginer](http://www.ebay.com/itm/151420796906).  But that doesn't sound very safe, especially since the linked device only sends the RFID device ID.

Answer (score 3):

In earlier versions of OS X (i.e. 10.9 and older) you had the /usr/sbin/pcscd executable, which the driver that comes with your ACR122T dongle can talk to.

In the latest OS X (10.10), pcscd has been replaced by something new called com.apple.ctkpcscd, which will be running in a default install of Yosemite.

The documentation for this new daemon is available from:

https://smartcardservices.macosforge.org

Here you can also get the source code, etc.